# Python dictionary argument error

Tags: python, dictionary, raspberry-pi

I'm actually write a control program for the GPIO Ports of my Raspberry Pi, I program it in python and wanted to do it with a dictionary.

Okay, to set a GPIO port it needs 2 arguments and as you can see in the dictionary table, I used two arguments which you should get when you write something like "00".

For example, the code to be able control a GPIO port is:

```
output(11, low)
```

As you can see in the dictionary, I should get two arguments back like in the code above, but still I'm getting an error that just one argument is there and not two. Here's my code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from RPi.GPIO import input as input
from RPi.GPIO import output as output
from RPi.GPIO import HIGH as high
from RPi.GPIO import LOW as low
from time import sleep as sleep


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
entry = raw_input("Which port you want to control?:")

while entry != "xx" :
    io = {
       '00' : "11, low",
       '01' : "11, high", 
       '10' : "12, low", 
       '11' : "12, high",
       '20' : "13, low", 
       '21' : "13, high", 
       '30' : "15, low", 
       '31' : "15, high", 
       '40' : "16, low", 
       '41' : "16, high", 
       '50' : "18, low", 
       '51' : "18, high", 
       '60' : "22, low", 
       '61' : "22, high", 
       '70' : "7, low", 
       '71' : "7, high", 
       '80' : "3, low", 
       '81' : "3, high", 
       '90' : "5, low", 
       '91' : "5, high", 
       '100' : "24, low", 
       '101' : "24, high", 
       '110' : "26, low", 
       '111' : "26, high", 
       '120' : "19, low", 
       '121' : "19, high", 
       '130' : "21, low", 
       '131' : "21, high", 
       '140' : "23, low", 
       '141' : "23, high", 
       '150' : "8, low", 
       '151' : "8, high", 
       '160' : "10, low", 
       '161' : "10, high"
       }

    output(io[entry])
    entry = raw_input("Which port you want to control?:")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
io = {
       '00' : "11, low",
       '01' : "11, high", 
       # snip...
}
```

Make your values tuples:

```
io = {
    '00': (11, low),
    '01': (11, high)
    # etc...
}
```

Then unpack them as arguments to your `output`, eg:

```
output(*io[entry])
```

At the moment, you're trying to pass `output` a single string of `11, high` while it appears  to require two arguments: an integer and one of either the `high` or `low` values.

**Side note:**

I'd also move the `io` assignment outside the loop (no point keep setting it) and change the `while` to a `for` utilising the two-argument `iter`, eg:

```
io = { ... }
for entry in iter(lambda: raw_input('Which port?: '), 'xx'):
    output(*io[entry])
    # rest of stuff...
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the problem is gone now, but now I'm getting a runtime error. "No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root" and of course, I'm running it as a root.

Comment: @Jagson can't help you with that one I'm afraid... I don't have a Raspberry Pi - and to be fair that's no longer a programming issue :) You may have better luck with those sorts of issues on another SE site: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/